# Android Bluetooth socket connection receiving data in background with AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-asynctask, bluetooth

I'm a noob in Android, I'm making an application that connects the phone with Arduino via Bluetooth, the phone sends data when the user presses some buttons but the problem is that the phone must be expecting to receive data continuously without stop the application, and when the phone receives data must update a listview and two textview and keep waiting to receive data another time. I have read that I must use a class that extends of AsyncTask but after reading many things still I do not understand how it works. In the main class the onCreate method execute the thread and would have some like this:

```
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListaAlertas);
TextView textTemp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.NumeroTemperatura);
TextView textHum = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.NumeroHumedad);
Receptor task = new Receptor(listView, textTemp,textHum);
task.execute();
```

And the class Receptor I have read something like this:

```
public class Receptor extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    private WeakReference<ListView> list;
    private WeakReference<TextView> temp;
    private WeakReference<TextView> hum;
    BluetoothSocket socketReceptor;
    InputStream inpReceptor;
    OutputStream outReceptor;

    public Receptor(ListView view, TextView view2, TextView view3) {
        this.list = new WeakReference<ListView>(view);
        this.temp = new WeakReference<TextView>(view2);
        this.hum = new WeakReference<TextView>(view3);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            socketReceptor = SocketSingleton.getSocket();
            inpReceptor = socketReceptor.getInputStream();
            outReceptor = socketReceptor.getOutputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[25];
            int read = inpReceptor.read(buffer);
            while(read != -1){
                publishProgress(read);
                read = inpReceptor.read(buffer);
            }

            inpReceptor.close();
            outReceptor.close();
            socketReceptor.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have the socket in the SocketSingleton class and now I just want to wait reading until I have something to receive and then update the listView and the two textView that belong to the main class and back again to wait reading until I have something new to receive. I do not understand how the AsyncTask works so I need help, sorry for my English and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use asynctask and wants to update the listview when any data received then you can use publishProgress method in asynchtask which i see you are already using it.

You may just need to add this function to receive the progress and in that function you can update the listview.

```
 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     //Update the progress on listview
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to use Async Tasks for this. They are preferred for short tasks. As you need the socket to continuously listen for data.

Implement a Background Service https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html and use a Receiver https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html to get the data to your Activity.